# Java.Lang.IllegalAccessError on all programs after upgrading to a new computer

Tags: java, illegalaccessexception

I got a new computer yesterday (Dell XPS 13). I just installed the JDK and copied all of my old Java projects over to my new device, but when I try to run any of these programs I get an illegal access error.

Edit: Note: Before the upgrade I was using jdk1.8.0_151. I am now using jdk-12.0.2.

I've tried recompiling all of the classes within some of the projects, but this doesn't help. Note that the illegal access error only occurs at runtime. I've seen other stackoverflow posts about illegal access errors, but none of their solutions worked for me.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class Tree from class BinTree (Tree is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; BinTree is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @48a242ce)
    at BinTree.main(BinTree.Java:12)
```

Edit: The project hierarchy for this project is:

```
    BinTree:
        Tree:
            Node
```

Edit: This is the main class of the project:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    class BinTree {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Create randomized values for a new tree 
            ArrayList<Double> toSort = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1300; i++) {
                double rand = 1 + ((int)(Math.random()*100000));
                toSort.add(rand);
            }
            //Create tree
            Tree binTree = new Tree(toSort);
            binTree.getGreatestNode();
            binTree.sort();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Were your projects on Java 9 before the upgrade?

Comment: Can you please share the code of your main class?

Comment: Can you post your project's package hierarchy? This should be easy to solve once you can create a `module-info.java` in your project.

Comment: @JacobG. Yes. I will post the hierarchy of a simpler project with fewer classes for the sake of simplicity. I will also switch the error message to that of the simpler project.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Before the upgrade I was using jdk 1.8.0_151. I am now using jdk-12.0.2.

Comment: @RakibulIslam code shared above

Comment: @Mezex Can you please share also the steps you have followed for recompiling the classes

Comment: @RakibulIslam when I recompiled the classes I simply deleted all of the .class files and recompiled each class individually

Comment: Maybe try explicitly importing the classes. Or declare a Java Module, so your classes aren't in unnamed automodules. I'll try playing with it and see if I can learn something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile all the `.java` source file of your project at once. If you have all three files `BinTree`, `Tree` and `Node` in the same directory, then you can easily go to that directory using cmd/terminal and write:

```
javac *.java
```

It should compile all the java file on that directory at once.

Comment: They are all in the same directory. I ran "javac *.java". All compiled without fail. However I am still getting the same illegal access error.

Comment: It's probably the use of some testing library that does reflection calls that are no longer supported.